# php/wordpress: how to "superimpose" data on a government pdf form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, pdf

I have a Wordpress website. I'd like to allow users to download (and/or print) a government issued form (in pdf) that is already filled with data supplied from the website's database (such as name, address, amount paid, etc.).

Before getting stuck in coding php, are there any Wordpress plugins that can do this already (I am new to Wordpress)? I have Gravity Forms already btw.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Wordpress, but this is pretty simple to do in PHP using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/).

```
<?php

require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

// get the page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('base.pdf');
// iterate through all pages
$pageNo = 1;
// import a page
$templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
// get the size of the imported page
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

// create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
    $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
} else {
    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
}

// use the imported page
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

// set the font typeface and size
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->setFontSize(20);


// set position where to write
$pdf->SetXY(10, 10);
$pdf->Write(8, 'Hello World!');

// don't save a local copy, but instead output stream to the browser
$pdf->Output("output.pdf", "I");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-pdf-extended/

- Save PDF File on user submission of a Gravity Form so it can be
  attached to a notification
- Customise the PDF template without affecting the core Gravity Form
  Plugin
- Multiple PDF Templates
- Custom PDF Name
- Output individual form fields in the template - like MERGETAGS
- View and download a PDF via the administrator interface or after a
  user submits their form
- Works with Gravity Forms Signature Add-On

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Pasting the gravity forms plugin source code does not seem like a good idea.. As the answer describes what plugin he could use, the link is just a reference to it. But you right, link-only answers are not an answer.